# Could we have a [tour] short link in comments?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, tour, magic-links

In comments,

- `[help]` expands to the text *help center* (with a link),
- `[chat]` expands to the text *Role-playing Games Chat* (with a link),
- `[edit]` becomes a link to edit the current question, and
- `[tour]` does nothing at all.

Comment: I had no idea these existed and you have vastly improved my life by informing me that they do.

Comment: You're most welcome, @KRyan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[tour] now also links to the tour.

Answer (score 12):

The [about] quick link goes to the tour.

Comment: Yeah, I use this almost every day.

Comment: Totally breaks the 4-character pattern though!