# How long has [tour] automatically linked to the tour page?

Tags: discussion, tour, magic-links, markdown

I was linking to the tour page as I usually do in Markdown (square brackets followed by parentheses) when I noticed that typing "[tour]" was linking to the tour page by itself and the link in parentheses was just being displayed as plain text.

Is this a recent addition to the site, or have I just been oblivious to it all this time?

Comment: Did you know there's also `[edit]`, `[help]`, and `[chat]`?

Comment: I did not. This is a whole new world of tags.

Comment: Years, at any rate. Most of [the comment shortcuts](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) have been around for a long time, long enough for several rounds of feature requests to ask for expansions.

Comment: http://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3301/4398

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I can tell, comment shortcuts have been around since basically forever.

The [tour] link got added sometime soon before [June 6, 2014](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6343/1204) (officially confirmed on [June 11](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228303/152515)†), a short while after our About page instead became a Tour, and references to it got renamed accordingly over the next few months. Before then, however, we used [about] to refer to the same page, so it's not so much a new link as a new name for an old link.

Like TuggyNE and Nitsua60 posted in comments [there's a bunch of post shortcuts like this](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), including one to every Stack Exchange site (our shortcut is [rpg.se]).

---

† <sub>BESW reported this being implemented a whole week before the staff did. Upcoming, a new meta on whether BESW is a time traveler.</sub>

Comment: Maybe being a time traveler comes with the territory of being a [gestalt entity](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11?m=27954368#27954368)?