# Is there a quick way to link to the help center?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, help-center, magic-links

I learned from a meta post by HeyICanChan once that you can type [tour] in a comment and SE will convert that into a link to the tour page.

Is there a similar way to link to the help center?

It's common practice these days to link both in "greetings" comments to new users, but I have to copy the full URL link and insert that into the comment (using the [text] (URL) notation), which takes up space and isn't as quick as [tour].

Comment: Let's try [help]

Comment: The [comment formatting](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) section of the edit help page lists all the available shortcut links (remembered seeing it brought up before, searched and found from [this answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6553/28402)).

Comment: @Carcer Make that an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Related: [Could we have a \[tour\] short link in comments?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3301/could-we-have-a-tour-short-link-in-comments), [How long has \[tour\] automatically linked to the tour page?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6552/how-long-has-tour-automatically-linked-to-the-tour-page)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [comment formatting](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) section of the editing help pages lists all the available shortcut links you can use in comments, including `[help]` for the help center. As of posting that is:

> `[meta]` – link to the current site's Meta; link text is the site name
>   (e.g. "Super User Meta"). Does nothing if the site doesn't have (or
>   already is) a Meta site.
>
> `[main]` – like [meta], just the other way around.
>
> `[edit]` – link to the edit page for the post the comment is on, i.e.
>   /posts/{id}/edit. Link text is "edit" (capitalization is respected).
>
> `[tag:tagname]` and `[meta-tag:tagname]` – link to the given tag's page.
>   Link text is the name of the tag.meta-tag only works on meta sites.
>
> `[help]`, `[help/on-topic]`, `[help/dont-ask]`, `[help/behavior]` and
>   `[meta-help]` – link to frequently visited pages of the help center.
>   Link text is "help center" (capitalization is respected). All links
>   point to the main site.
>
> `[tour]` – link to the Tour page. Link text is "tour" (capitalization is
>   respected).
>
> `[so]`, `[pt.so]`, `[su]`, `[sf]`, `[metase]`, `[a51]`, `[se]` – link to the given
>   site. Link text is the site name.
>
> `[chat]` – link to the current site's chat site, the link text being
>   "{site name} Chat".
>
> `[ask]`, `[answer]` – link to the How to Ask or How to Answer page.
>
> `[something.se]` – link to something.stackexchange.com, if that site
>   exists. Link text is the site name. Use `[ubuntu.se]` for Ask Ubuntu.

as remembered from [this answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6553/28402)

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful. I never knew this page existed before now (although I admit I never went looking for it).

Comment: I will go ahead and admit that I didn't know about this page, even having tried to find it, so I think this Q&A is useful to help people learn about one of the many secret features of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I just figured it out. It's [help], which is converted into the text "help center".